# After upgrade on Mountain Lion postgresql doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.1, osx-mountain-lion

I just updated my Macbook to Mountain Lion, but now postgresql doesn't work. I get the following error message when I let rails server running :

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::Error)
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

-UPDATE- Now I get the following error message:

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 3.1.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-29 11:54:46 +0200

PGError (could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
):
```

Comment: @Chiyou - this is nothing to do with kernel packages - OSX is not Linux

Comment: @Chiyou - actually much it is simpler not using the kernel:)  - would you please delete your comments so we can start this again except for the find mkmf.log as there are too many comments here

Comment: @nadine1988: reinstall ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711394/pg-gem-0-14-0-on-mountain-lion-fails

Comment: First, verify that you can connect using `psql` and that the server is actually running.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have make, autconf, automake, binutils, bison installed, m4 or install the package to build a kernel or reinstall ruby: [pg gem '0.14.0' on Mountain Lion fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711394/pg-gem-0-14-0-on-mountain-lion-fails).

Comment: $ locate mkmf.log

WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.

Comment: $ find / -name "mkmf.log"
find: /.DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission denied
find: /.fseventsd: Permission denied
find: /.Spotlight-V100: Permission denied
find: /.Trashes: Permission denied   ----------   how can I check if I have everything installed?