# Error while building bundle due to pg gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pg gem ‘0.14.0’ on Mountain Lion fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711394/pg-gem-0-14-0-on-mountain-lion-fails)

I had a perfectly good rails env on one of my OSX machines but then I had to install a cross compiler for OS161 for a school project and it destroyed my rails environment. I tried to set up an environment (the same environment actually) on a different OSX machine and I get this error while trying to run bundle install:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config 
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
checking for PQprepare()... yes
checking for PQexecParams()... yes
checking for PQescapeString()... yes
checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
checking for PQescapeLiteral()... yes
checking for PQescapeIdentifier()... yes
checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
checking for lo_create()... yes
checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
checking for pg_char_to_encoding()... yes
checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
checking for PQlibVersion()... yes
checking for PQping()... yes
checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
checking for rb_enc_alias()... no
checking for PGRES_COPY_BOTH in libpq-fe.h... no
checking for PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE in libpq-fe.h... no
checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
compiling pg.c
pg.c: In function ‘Init_pg_ext’:
pg.c:384: error: ‘PQPING_OK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pg.c:384: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
pg.c:384: error: for each function it appears in.)
pg.c:386: error: ‘PQPING_REJECT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pg.c:388: error: ‘PQPING_NO_RESPONSE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pg.c:390: error: ‘PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [pg.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.14.1 for       inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing pg (0.14.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.14.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Can someone please help? I've been trying to find the solution for two days now...